# eclipse rcp product set tab style not work

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I develop a rcp product with eclipse kepler(Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers), but set tab style not work.
I tried two ways

1.config.xml

```
<extension  id="product" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
 <product  application="cn.desktoptool.application" name="cn.test">
     <property name="preferenceCustomization" value="plugin_customization.ini"/>
 </product>
```

and plugin_customization.ini file

```
org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_TRADITIONAL_STYLE_TABS=false
```

2.add code in class ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor

```
PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue( IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_TRADITIONAL_STYLE_TABS, false);
```

but not work, What's the problem？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This preference is not used in Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) because the styling is controlled by `CSS`.

To change the tab style you either define your own style or you can edit one of the existing `css` files (in the `org.eclipse.platform` plugin `css` directory).

The tab style is controlled by the `swt-simple` property, usually set for the `.MPartStack` class:

```
.MPartStack {
    swt-simple: true;
    .. other properties ...
}
```

`true` gives you the traditional tabs.

More information on css styling and creating styles here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CSS/article.html